# convert a list to column names

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Please find the input and desired output in the image attached.

[image]

Comment: attach the screenshot of the dataframe or use proper formatting.

Comment: Yes, I cannot comprehend the question

Comment: I am new here, its showing fine in my edit age. but i have added a image. pls see if that helps, and if possible please answer too.

Comment: Add the code to generate the input dataframe also so that it is easy for people to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first `explode` on Hobbies column and then `groupby` name and hobbies to get the `count`, and have it as a `frame` and then just do the `pivoting` where `Name` is the index, `Hobbies` holds the new column names you want and values is the `count` of a given hobby. You can do `fillna(0)` at last to fill `NaN` with zeroes.

```py
result = df.explode('Hobbies').groupby(['Name', 'Hobbies']).size().\
to_frame('counts').reset_index().\
pivot(index='Name', columns='Hobbies', values='counts').reset_index().fillna(0)
result
Out[16]: 
Hobbies Name  cook  dance  movies  sing
0          A   0.0    1.0     1.0   1.0
1          B   1.0    1.0     1.0   0.0
```

If you want, you can merge these new columns back to original dataframe.

```py
df = df[['Name', 'Hobbies']].merge(result)
df
Out[17]: 
  Name                Hobbies  cook  dance  movies  sing
0    A  [sing, dance, movies]   0.0    1.0     1.0   1.0
1    B  [movies, cook, dance]   1.0    1.0     1.0   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Many answers are posted but they seem complicated for no reason

**This is how your dataframe looks like**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'Name': 'A', 'Hobbies': ['sing','dance','movies']}, 
                       {'Name': 'B', 'Hobbies': ['movies','cook','dance']}])
```

**This will be my way of simplifying things -**

```
# Map out hobbies list to create new hobbies column at same index. 

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for each_hobby in row.Hobbies:
        df.loc[index, each_hobby] = True

df.fillna(False, inplace=True) # Fill NaN values with False.
df.replace({False: 0, True: 1}, inplace=True) # Map out False to 0 and True to 1.
```

Output :

```
>>> df

Out[3]: 
   Name         Hobbies       sing  dance  movies  cook
0    A  [sing, dance, movies]   1      1      1      1
1    B  [movies, cook, dance]   0      1      1      1
```